# Extracting the underlying type in the template

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am new to C++20. The intention here is to have a template class which has `value` whose type would be the underlying type of `T` that's passed in.

So in case of `T` being:

- `std::optional<char>`, it's `char value`
- `int`, it's just `int value`.

1. Is there any better way to extract the types than through `struct TypeExtract`? More or a generic solution in C++20 perhaps? Given if the class could take more than just `std::optional<int>` or just a primitive type?
2. Can the condition in `foo` be improved specially with the way `val` is initialized?

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>> = true;


template<typename T>
struct TypeExtract 
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct TypeExtract<std::optional<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
concept is_integral = std::is_integral_v<typename TypeExtract<T>::type>;

template <is_integral T>
class A
{
    using Type = typename TypeExtract<T>::type;
    Type val;

    void foo(T value)
    { 
      if constexpr (is_optional<T>)
      {
        val = *value;
      } 
      else
      {
        val = value;
      }
    }
};


int main()
{
   A<char> a1;
   A<std::optional<int>> a2;
   // A<double> a3; // fails
}
```

Comment: depressing.  what real world problem would this solve, if you could do it (i'm not saying you can't)?

Comment: This is a very strange example. `optional<int>` satisfying something called `is_integral` is.... surprising, since it's very much not integral. But then, what're you doing in `A<T>::foo`? Why do you need to dereference `value` in this case, `T val = value;` works just fine?

Comment: Depending on what you really want to achieve, you can just create a concept that requires an inner `value_type` and it might simplify things a great way. Or maybe dereferencable type, e.g. any kind of pointer+optional. My point is: state you exact requirements, please, "more than just optional" is quite a broad one.

Comment: I'm wondering which other types could reasonably be supported here. `std::tuple<int>` ? `std::unique_ptr<int>` ? `int*` ?

Comment: @alagner just the `std::optional` and a primitive integral type

Comment: @MSalters for now atleast it's `std::optional` and/or any primitive type. It's a library which would be used by users but these two make the most sense.

Comment: One more question then: what is the desired operation of `foo`? Is it supposed to assign to a class member, the other way around? Currently the code just creates a temporary of type T and assigns to it. It works somewhat by accident thanks to built-in converting assignment of std::optional but I'm close to certain it's not doing what you intended. ;)

Comment: @alagner what makes you think it's not doing what's intended? if `T` is optional, it's gotta dereference prior to storing in `val` which is of the underlying type. `foo` is just initializing `val`

Comment: Both `val` and `value` are of type `T`, i.e. they are of the same type in the context of `foo` and they are both temporaries, note the function body. The other `value` at the class scope (the member) is of the underlying type. I assumed a typing mistake and that `foo`’s argument is supposed to be assigned to the member but needed your comfirmation on this.

Comment: @alagner my bad. I realized I had a typo there. Thanks. `val` is of the underlying type where `value` of type `T` which could be `std::optional<char>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to extract first template parameter from a class template and keep on unwinding templates until you get to a non-template type. In that case you could make a type trait that is specialized for types instantiated from templates:

```cpp
// primary template
template<class T, class...>
struct type {
    using value_type = T;
};

// specialization for template instantiated types
template<template<class, class...> class T, class F, class... Rest>
struct type<T<F, Rest...>> {
    using value_type = typename type<F>::value_type;
};

// helper alias
template<class... Ts>
using type_t = typename type<Ts...>::value_type;
```

You could then use it like so:

```cpp
int main() {
   type_t<char> a1;
   type_t<std::optional<int>> a2;
   type_t<double, int> a3;

   static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a1), char>);
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a2), int>);
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a3), double>);
}
```

Comment: I like your answer. Still I wonder what the OP really wants; personally I'd just take advantage of the fact that optional, as well as several other standard types declare value_type inside.

Comment: @alagner Thanks. Yes, I'm not 100% sure this is what OP needs. Using `value_type` often works but one will have to take some extra precaution with that. In a `map` it'll be `std::pair<const Key, T>` while the first template parameter is `Key` so `std::remove_const_t` will probably have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good or bad here, it's a matter of style and convention, but personally I would get rid of `if constexpr` and take advantage of trailing requires for the sake of reducing function's cyclomatic complexity. On the other hand, that add some boilerplate. The choice is yours.

Not much can be done about type extraction, though I would probably use a templated base and import its member(s) instead of importing the type into the class. Not a big deal, but it feels more idiomatic to me.

As for concepts, I'd probably use more library-provided ones in the place of type traits.

Side note: consider using `assert`, `.value()` or similar function when assigning from the optional to ensure it's not empty.

All in all, I'd probably write your code somewhat this way:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
concept StdOptional = std::same_as<std::optional<typename T::value_type>, T>;

template<typename T>
concept OptionalIntegral = StdOptional<T> and std::integral<typename T::value_type>;

template<typename T>
concept OptionalOrOptionalIntegral = std::integral<T> or OptionalIntegral<T>;

template<typename>
struct ABase;

template<std::integral T>
struct ABase<T>
{
    T value;
};

template<OptionalIntegral T>
struct ABase<T>
{
    typename T::value_type value;
};

template<OptionalOrOptionalIntegral T>
class A : ABase<T>
{
    using ABase<T>::value;

public:
    void setValue(T val) requires(std::integral<T>)
    {
        value = val;
    }

    void setValue(T val) requires(OptionalIntegral<T>)
    {
        value = val.value();
    }
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/dzvr9xbGr